# Please translate to American English from the British the following: OH **UK!

Tags: phrases, american-english, british-english

The cover of the most recent [*Economist* (March 16 - 22nd 2019)](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2019/03/14/oh-uk-what-next-for-brexit) has in large type

> **OH **UK! Whatever next?**

From the context, this is clearly a comment on the current Brexit mess.

Is ** UK  related to F * * K, and if so, how?  Did the Economist transpose ***C*** and ***U*** to be more polite?  Or, more likely, does UK refer to the United Kingdom, and if so, how do we interpret ** ?

This should be obvious, and I will probably hit myself on the head when it is explained, but for now the inscrutable Brits have me baffled.

Googling **UK gets me many referenced to the UK (the nation), but no explanation of the **.

Comment: It's a kind of pun clearly meant to make you *think* of F**K, but identifying that with *UK* because Brexit is an issue for the UK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article is pretty clearly about the UK and it's also portraying a situation where "oh fuck" would be an appropriate thing to say. However, they can't use "fuck" and still have the joke work. So "**UK" could stand for "fcuk" (it wouldn't be the first time [a joke like this was made](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23clusterfcuk%20brexit&src=typd)) or it could stand for "[phuk](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phuk)", which is basically an alternate slang spelling of "fuck". Or it might not stand for any letters in particular; the point is for you to know it means "oh fuck".

(I don't think this has anything to do with British English.)

Comment: +1 Laurel "I don't think this has anything to do with British English."

Comment: A retailer has built their [particular brand](https://www.frenchconnection.com/content/category/fcuk.htm) on the joke. But yes, it's not restricted to British English, although the transposition of letters to make it relevant to the UK might restrict any global appeal.

Comment: Australia's Northern Territory is probably too small a market for this type of thing.